# Jaspersoft: Change textfield borders depending on params

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm working with jasperStudio 6.3.1 and Java 8.

I have a report and a subreport, and shipping status (received, sent, new, requested, cancelled).

The subreport has a textField with full square borders, and I want to have just the bottom line border, but without doing another subreport just for it.

I was wondering if there's any way to change the style (related to the textfield border) or change directly the border, depending on a parameter that I can get from Java.

(It already takes the shipping status as a parameter).

(**edit:** jaspersoft crashes everytime I create a new style (it's a bug not resolved yet), so creating a new style in not an option)

Answer (score 0):

There's an option called "PrintWhenExpression" you can use for it. Or link a style to a parameter.
Using printWhenExpression for each field requires a duplicate field and less scalability.

But I think it's the only option since creating a style makes it crash in JasperStudio 6.3.1.
(Also you can update it if you need and set compatibility)